# Client have doubled cookie name and browser send to server the wrong one

Tags: php, http, session, cookies

Website *mydomain.com* with php server worked fine with below cookie settings:

```
domain=null
secure=false
path=/
http-only=true
same-site=null
```

Once i changed the cookie domain on *".mydomain.com"* clients started receiving cookies with *".mydomain.com"* domain, but the old ones with *"mydomain.com"* domain were not removed. After that, each request to the server contains both old and new cookies with different values. The order of cookies with same name in the header is unpredictable. The server puts in the `$_COOKIE` var only those cookies that come first in order.

The problem is that the correct cookie is the one that comes after another with same name in the cookie header. How can I remove the old cookie with *"mydomain.com"* domain ? Or how can I get correct cookie from the client?

Comment: _"How can I remove the old cookie with `mydomain.com` domain ?"_ - by _setting_ it again, with the domain set to null, and an expiry in the past?

Comment: To do that, I need to know name of all cookies and delete them one by one, but my cookies has encrypted names

Comment: You should already have some way of knowing the names of the cookies, right? If not, how would you even use them!?

Comment: And even if i will know about encrypted names, there is too many different cookies that settings up in different situations, it will take many time for finding them all

Comment: _"The problem is that the correct cookie is the one that comes after another with same name in the cookie header."_ - then get the raw request headers, and parse them yourself ...

Comment: Cookie in the header has no domain parameter, I can't detect the right one. Well, the solution "setting it again, with the domain set to null, and an expiry in the past" really can help, but maybe there is more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just redefine cookies i want to remove with expiry option in the past like this:

```
setcookie('cookieName', '', 1, '/', 'mydomain.com');
```

Using [this](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) function. And 'path' cookie option is also important to specify, because the cookie with different path - is different cookie.

Thanks to [@cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73609309/client-have-doubled-cookie-name-and-browser-send-to-server-the-wrong-one?noredirect=1#comment129986274_73609309) for help.